# Azure Pipelines (DevOps): Custom Consumable Statistic/Metric

Tags: azure, azure-devops, customization, azure-pipelines, badge

I have a build up on Azure Pipelines, and one of the steps provides a code metric that I would like to have be consumable after the build is done. Ideally, this would be in the form of a badge [like this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a0597f724bf78fc584d53513c7750b1a8f8dd735/68747470733a2f2f696d672e736869656c64732e696f2f6e756765742f64742f417264616c69732e4775617264436c61757365732e737667) (where we have text on the left and the metric in the form of a number on the right). I'd like to put such a badge on the `README` of the repository to make this metric visible on a per-build basis.

Azure DevOps does have a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) that one can use to access built-in aspects of a given build. But as far as I can tell there's no way to expose a *custom* statistic or value that is generated or provided during a build.

(The equivalent in TeamCity would be outputting `##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='My Custom Metric' value='123']` via `Console.WriteLine()` from a simple C# program, that TeamCity can then consume and use/make available.)

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I think you will need to check Azure Devops extensions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops take a look at the countdown sample https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.CountdownWidget

Comment: Maybe see if this is what you are looking for:  https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/2237

Comment: Do you want to expose the statistic in a bulid variable during the build?

Comment: @AnassKartit Looked it over. Extensions may be the way to go but the examples provided don't necessarily get at the crux of the issue ("I need to use a metric that is not part of the build pipeline by default, but is in fact generated by the build itself.") Will dig.

Comment: @Matt that's step 2. :) Step 1 is exposing my custom value on the API (or somewhere consumable) .

Comment: If you want the value, it is probably this:  `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/codecoverage?buildId=${buildId}&api-version=5.0-preview.1`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk ideally, I want to be able to display this metric on the `README` of the project this is for. Like how you can show a "Build Successful" or "All Tests Passed" message/badge based off the latest build for a project. "Latest Build Custom Value: 45" or something is what I'd like to do.

Comment: @Matt my question is "how do I get my custom value on that API" :) It currently doesn't exist and is not part of the default Code Coverage values provided.

Comment: check the countdown example

Answer (score 0):

One option is you could use a combination of adding a build tag using a command:

```
##vso[build.addbuildtag]"My Custom Metric.123"
```

Then use the Tags - Get Build Tags [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/get%20build%20tags?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/tags?api-version=5.0
```

Comment: Giving this a try! When I let Azure build it and I attempt to `Console.WriteLine()` a `##vso[build.addbuildtag]"My Custom Metric:123"`, however, I get `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).` It apparently doesn't like `:`. What's the proper way to output that `addbuildtag` command?

Comment: Sorry, I've not used the commands from C#.  My only experience has been calling them from powershell.  The documentation for them is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: @Scott I think you can't use `:` becuase the rest API not allowed it. try to remove the `:`.